# How to clean up multiple git merges

Tags: git

I have merged branches several times without realizing that it worked the first time and thus messed up the git history. Now I would like to clean up the git history if possible. I would like the "Merge branch 'development' of https://... into development" to disappear or to reduced it to one entry in the git history. How could I do that?

Below is a screenshot of the history and a git log at the end of this post.

**Edit**: I am not sure, if I managed to express my desired result properly. My main concern is to clean up the history. The graphic below shows my current git history. I would like to squash the marked commits and merges together.

[image: The merges and commits I would like to squash together.]

```
|
:
|
*   commit 5c36203c6d995e11138ccdc79a9daa86cf05aeb7 (origin/development_initial, feature/project-ToolManager, development_initial)
|\  Merge: 8564fae 3dc0393
| | Author: Drimer
| | Date:   Fri Mar 4 12:48:17 2022 +0100
| |
| |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| |
| *   commit 3dc03939829e05b2431f8e3c6a353f2da308b2a1
| |\  Merge: bf2f283 f2e18a9
| | | Author: Drimer
| | | Date:   Fri Mar 4 11:27:27 2022 +0100
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| | |
* | |   commit 8564fae1510d4dd1a318f5b223d822d2effe591e
|\ \ \  Merge: bf2f283 f2e18a9
| |/ /  Author: Drimer
|/| /   Date:   Fri Mar 4 11:27:27 2022 +0100
| |/
| |         Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| |
| *   commit f2e18a9fd2c7dd67626b205e7ad765066f3db1ca
| |\  Merge: 6b53b37 3a603f2
| | | Author: Drimer
| | | Date:   Thu Mar 3 16:03:44 2022 +0100
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| | |
| | *   commit 3a603f2cad073dcfabf2b9c239b9eb82c238e8d2
| | |\  Merge: f49ff40 e3ccdc4
| | | | Author: Drimer
| | | | Date:   Tue Mar 1 15:15:58 2022 +0100
| | | |
| | | |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| | | |
| * | | commit 6b53b37fdd909be9ebc1b30abe315dabc2524336
| | |/  Author: Drimer
| |/|   Date:   Thu Mar 3 16:03:32 2022 +0100
| | |
| | |       Added a check ...
| | |
* | | commit bf2f2839f84ceb52fafe6de1463b106cdafb55fb
|\| | Merge: f49ff40 e3ccdc4
| |/  Author: Drimer
|/|   Date:   Tue Mar 1 15:15:58 2022 +0100
| |
| |       Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| |
| * commit e3ccdc485fd6364776c0f1a3d4ea2d4b54ea5f64
| | Author: Drimer
| | Date:   Tue Mar 1 14:48:24 2022 +0100
| |
| |     Load ...
| |
* | commit f49ff4065812c4a4f045c97c5817be326a4bbef6
|/  Author: Drimer
|   Date:   Tue Mar 1 14:48:24 2022 +0100
|
|       Load ...
|
*   commit c7424d0925d9b9ff5e821fe070b8dfd2bd89109e
|\  Merge: 2eb50d7 c71d5c0
| | Author: Drimer
| | Date:   Tue Mar 1 14:17:20 2022 +0100
| |
| |     Merge branch 'feature/project0003-resource-file' into development
| |
| |     # Conflicts:
:
|
*   commit 5c36203c6d995e11138ccdc79a9daa86cf05aeb7 (origin/development_initial, feature/project-ToolManager, development_initial)
|\  Merge: 8564fae 3dc0393
| | Author: Drimer
| | Date:   Fri Mar 4 12:48:17 2022 +0100
| |
| |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| |
| *   commit 3dc03939829e05b2431f8e3c6a353f2da308b2a1
| |\  Merge: bf2f283 f2e18a9
| | | Author: Drimer
| | | Date:   Fri Mar 4 11:27:27 2022 +0100
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| | |
* | |   commit 8564fae1510d4dd1a318f5b223d822d2effe591e
|\ \ \  Merge: bf2f283 f2e18a9
| |/ /  Author: Drimer
|/| /   Date:   Fri Mar 4 11:27:27 2022 +0100
| |/
| |         Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| |
| *   commit f2e18a9fd2c7dd67626b205e7ad765066f3db1ca
| |\  Merge: 6b53b37 3a603f2
| | | Author: Drimer
| | | Date:   Thu Mar 3 16:03:44 2022 +0100
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| | |
| | *   commit 3a603f2cad073dcfabf2b9c239b9eb82c238e8d2
| | |\  Merge: f49ff40 e3ccdc4
| | | | Author: Drimer
| | | | Date:   Tue Mar 1 15:15:58 2022 +0100
| | | |
| | | |     Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| | | |
| * | | commit 6b53b37fdd909be9ebc1b30abe315dabc2524336
| | |/  Author: Drimer
| |/|   Date:   Thu Mar 3 16:03:32 2022 +0100
| | |
| | |       Added a check
| | |
* | | commit bf2f2839f84ceb52fafe6de1463b106cdafb55fb
|\| | Merge: f49ff40 e3ccdc4
| |/  Author: Drimer
|/|   Date:   Tue Mar 1 15:15:58 2022 +0100
| |
| |       Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development
| |
| * commit e3ccdc485fd6364776c0f1a3d4ea2d4b54ea5f64
| | Author: Drimer
| | Date:   Tue Mar 1 14:48:24 2022 +0100
| |
| |     Load ...
| |
* | commit f49ff4065812c4a4f045c97c5817be326a4bbef6
|/  Author: Drimer
|   Date:   Tue Mar 1 14:48:24 2022 +0100
|
|       Load ...
```

Comment: *I also wonder why the git log shows each commit twice* - it shouldn't. Each commit is uniquely identified by its hash ID. Each hash ID should appear only once. Yet searching for `6b53b37fdd909be9ebc1b30abe315dabc2524336` for instance, I see it twice. You ran `git log --graph` to get this? Perhaps there's a new bug in `git log --graph`... (Or, perhaps, it's a cut-and-paste error? Try redirecting `git log`'s output to a file, e.g., /tmp/log, and editing the file to trim off unwanted parts. See if the output is no longer doubled up.)

Comment: @torek, you are right. There seems to be a bug in the git log command. The posted log was created with the "git log --graph" command, but a "git log" contains the same commits.

Comment: Interesting. What version of Git are you running? And: If you can share the repository with the folks on the Git mailing list, any bug of this magnitude will probably get a fast fix.

Comment: The message can be the same, but the commit hash will be different. This usually hints at having rebased a branch and then merging (or pulling) the old and new history of the branch.

Comment: @torek, I use the version "2.33.0.windows.2".

Comment: @knittl, well the commit hashes, timestamps and messages are both the same.

Comment: The hash IDs *are* the commits. If the hash IDs are the same, the commits are the same. They should appear only once in any `git log` output because otherwise it means that `git log` has a potential infinite loop.

Comment: @torek, I just reinstalled git and `git log` produces a correct log now.

Comment: OK, so, some sort of bug, but fixed already, apparently.

Comment: (1) Why do you describe this history as "not clean"? It's what happened. I see nothing wrong with it. Why not leave it alone? (2) If the goal is to rewrite past history, what's wrong with the obvious and usual way, an interactive rebase? Are you implying there's some other way?

Answer (score 1):

If `bf2f2839f` worked i.e. has the content you want, and `5c36203c` is the last redundant attempt,

```
git replace 5c36203c bf2f2839f
git filter-branch -- --all
```

and it's all over but the pushing and any needed downstream rewriting (of history you didn't rewrite for them, based on the history you did).

---

edit: @LeGEC pointed out that the merges aren't completely redundant, there's additional commits you might want in your record.

To linearize a stretch of history from `base` to `tip`, where `tip` is the final merge and `base` is the newest ancestor you want to preserve, you can

```
git checkout base
git rev-list --topo-order --no-merges --reverse base..tip \
| git cherry-pick --stdin
git replace --graft tip @
```

with the rev-list | cherry-pick being pretty much what rebase does. Then if that produces a history you like, filter-branch to bake in the rewired ancestry in the remaining commits.

---

Be *very* careful about how you pick your replacements here, you're deep into "measure twice, cut once" territory.  Try this on a scratch clone and check the results,

```
git clone -s . `mktemp -d`
cd $_
git replace etc.
git filter-branch etc.
```

and then if you like the results you can push them back to your main local repo, if you don't you can just delete or abandon the wrecked local clone, no harm done.

See the docs for those commands, if you've got tags you'll want to say how to rewrite their names since published tags are normally not supposed ever to move, and perhaps you could add `--oneline` to your log command to lose all the not-needed-here details about each commit.

Comment: the `replace + filter-branch` trick is a very good option to combine together commits that have "no effect". In the OP's case, however, if you inspect closely the graph of commits in the part tangled with merge commits, there are a few commits which aren't merge commits, and which probably shouldn't be overlooked. Using the `replace` trick, would the modifications they bring be completely discarded ? I don't have a clear view of how `replace + filter-branch` works in that situation.

Comment: @LeGEC Replace is a straight replacement, if in `A---*---M---*---Y---Z` you `git replace Y A`, the only change is `Z`'s parent is now `A` so all the subsumed changes are still in `Z` but the history's gone.  You can try it casually, until you bake it in with a filter-branch backout's easy (with replace's `-d` option). OP could cherry-pick the commits he wants then replace the mess with the tip of the corrected intermediate history.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to :

a. get back to just before `ff5b6a3 LoadExtensio...`
b. squash all commits in one
c. replay all commits starting from `ff5b6a3` up to your current commit on top of the result

---

1. run `git rebase -i ff5b6a3^`

an editor will open, listing all the commits that `git rebase` has identified as "commits to keep" :

```
pick ff5b6a3 LoadExtensio...
pick 4477db6 Refactoring ...
...
```

2. insert a `break` instruction before the first line, then save and exit

```
break  # <- here
pick ff5b6a3 LoadExtensio...
pick 4477db6 Refactoring ...
...
```

`git` will display the message :

```
Stopped at 5c36203 (Merge branch 'development' of https://project into development)
```

and suspend the rebase, waiting for you to run `git rebase --continue` whenever you see fit.

-> you have now reach point *a.* above

3. run :

```
git reset --soft c7424d0 # <- use '--soft' to keep the changes in the staging area

# inspect the state of your code :
git diff --cached    # <- use '--cached' to view the *staged* modifications
# or
git difftool -d --cached

# if this is what you expect, create a commit with that :
git commit
```

-> you have now reached point *b.* : you now have a single commit which "combines" all the commits highlighted in your question

4. run

```
git rebase --continue
```

-> you have now reached point *c.*, and are done.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was the only one that worked for me right away. Thank you for that! But I also have a follow-up question: I deleted my repo's remote at the beginning (so I couldn't accidentally mess with the remote) and then followed your instructions. The history ended up being what I wanted it to be. Can I now just add the remote origin and force push all branches? Does the remote take over the current history or do I need to do some extra steps beforehand?

Comment: @Drimer: yes, you can re-add the remote, and force push to it. I think you know the general warnings about force push : if it's a shared repository, do check what you are overwriting, and warn you colleagues/users that they should rebase their work.

Answer (score 0):

Use rebase.

First at all, YOU CAN ALWAYS CANCEL WITH `git rebase --abort` command.

command like this

```bash
# first, count how many far from current index.
git log --oneline | grep -n "Merge branch"

# pick last number. if that is 5

git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

then you will see interactive editing view

```
pick abcdef12 my old merge commit <-- old
pick bacdef12 my old merge commit 2
pick cacdef12 my old merge commit 3
pick dacdef12 my old merge commit 4
pick ebcdef12 my current commit <--- current (git HEAD)
```

Change pick to fixup that you want to squash except first line. they would be squashed to oldest one.

flag as reword for editing commit message for squashing.

```
pick zbcdef12 more old commit but you don't want
pick ybcdef12 more old commit but you don't want 2
reword abcdef12 my old merge commit <--- they will be squashed this.
fixup bacdef12 my old merge commit 2
fixup cacdef12 my old merge commit 3
pick dacdef12 my old merge commit 4 which you don't want to merge
pick ebcdef12 my current commit <--- git HEAD
```

type `:wq`.

and then you will see like this.

```
my old merge commit

# Please enter the commit message blablablabla
```

Edit commit message like this: `Squashed: Implement awesome function and linting blablabla`

type `:wq`

and git will automatically squash commits `bacdef12` and `cacdef12` to abcdef12.

`git log --oneline` will show up like this:

```bash
ebcdef12 my current commit <--- current (git HEAD)
dacdef12 my old merge commit 4 which you don't want to merge
newhash Squashed: Implement awesome function and linting blablabla.
```

Comment: note that, by default, `git rebase` completely overlooks merge commits. In an interactive rebase they won't be listed in the commit list. You may try  to add `-r | --rebase-merges`, but this makes for a much more complicated rebase script in the editing window.

Comment: @LeGEC No, You don't have to use r option. Question is just 'how can squash commits that are middle in history?'. You can change pick to squash or fixup (or even 'edit' for manual work) that work in simple interactive mode. I agree it is so sensitive job but in this situation commits are dirty so this means forced push is allowed and remote should be arranged too.

Answer (score -1):

checkout the files of the revision you want, reset the branch (not the checkout) to the base revision, fast-import the files on the branch and done.